# SwitchResX and / or RDM do not activate desired scaled resolution

Tags: display, resolution, monterey

So i followed basically the answer in [this](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/410660/how-do-i-propery-configure-display-scaling-on-macos-with-a-1440p-external-displ/410664#410664) answer, but neither SwitchResX nor RDM activate 1920x1080 "HiDPI" resolution. I am using 2 LG UltraGear 27GP850 1440p displays. I saw someone else had the same issue, but there were no answers.

The only thing from the guide i didn't do was deactivating SIP, since this seems to be no longer needed in Monterey.

Did anybody face the same issue and maybe found a solution?

Comment: My Macbook is a Macbook Pro 2018, so Intel Mac.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed this problem. Everything done like in the linked guide, but I needed to select a 1920x1080 resolution with either 144hz or 120hz, the others won't work. But this only worked with SwitchResX for me.

Problem solved, hopefully this can help someone!